# org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: java, templates, email, velocity

I am using velocity engine template for mailing in struts1 and hibernate configuration.

I got error: `org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException` while I try to send mail.

I have included velocity1.5.jar, mail.jar, activation.jar, smtp.jar.

I include the velocity template path here

`String velocityTemplate = "mailTemplate/sendMail.vm";`

and the mailTemplate folder is in `WEB-INF/classes` folder

I got that error when code executes this line

`Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate(velocityTemplate);`

can any one help me regarding this?

It will be more appreciable if any one help me.

Comment: Which of the init() methods on the VelocityEngine did you call?

Comment: i am calling this one
Velocity.init();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As BenM said we have to configure the Resource Loader as a ClasspathResourceLoader

```
velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader"));

velocityEngine.init();
```

and I just added the latest version of the following jar. now it's working properly.

--> commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

--> commons-lang-2.4.jar

once again Thanks BenM

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have called init() on your VelocityEngine.

Check that you have configured your Resource Loader as a ClasspathResourceLoader. See the [Velocity docs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.2/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Resource_Loaders) for more info.

For the legacy Velocity class you'd do the following:

```
Velocity.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
Velocity.init();
```

Comment: could you please tell me where should that Resource Loader to be configured

Comment: do we need to configure any thing in web.xml ?
but i am using velocity only for mail

Comment: I've updated to show how to configure the class resource loader.

Comment: thank you Ben,
i have added that lines in my code but till the problem persist!.

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with the same issue, finally resolved it.

- template file needs to be in the class path.
- the velocity.properties file doesn't conflict with settings you make prior to init().
- and that there are not multiple jars of different versions littered around your project.