# ModalAndView to html string in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I need to send a mail with some HTML content,

but HTML content is in JSP file

I need to set data in JSP file for content, for this, I am using ModalAndView with addObject like this

```
ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView(PageConstants.wwEmail);
view.addObject("title",title);
view.addObject("content",html);
prepareEmailMessage(message, to, title, view.toString());
```

Am I doing it in the correct way? or is there any other way to do it?

How can I get HTML with populated data?

Comment: sorry I didn't it get clearly. Is your concern  how to populate jsp/html with your data or the data with view of the email to the recepient?

Comment: How do I get HTML content from the JSP page to send an email?

Comment: you can use any template engine like velocity, can check this out [example](https://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/spring-email-velocity-template-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user404 mentioned in the comment we can use velocity for this, 
by taking @Syed Shahul [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397727/3602846) as a reference, I have achieved my goal of using templates controller, This is my final solution

use these maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for we need to create a template(.vm) file for this in `src/main/resources`

then create a `VelocityEngine`

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
velocityEngine.init();
```

Now we need to generate a template with this `velocityEngine`

```
String page = "./ww_email.vm";
Template template = velocityEngine.getTemplate(page);
```

To pass data to the template we should use `VelocityContext`

```
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
velocityContext.put("title", title);
velocityContext.put("content", html);
```

Then create a StringWriter to obtain HTML string from template

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
```

Then merge this `stringWriter` with `velocityContext`

```
template.merge(velocityContext, stringWriter);
```

Finally, you can get HTML string like this

```
String htmlCodeString = stringWriter.toString()
```